# Strange errors after Process.Start()

Tags: c#, .net, process, system.diagnostics

I have a project which uses an external application to process moderately large files via a WebAPI service. A file is uploaded, some preprocessing and validation happens, then the work is handed off to the executable like so:

```
int result = -1;
try
{
    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = GetExePath(),
            Arguments = GetArguments(),
            WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(GetExePath()),
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        };
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit()
        result = process.ExitCode;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new ExecutionFailedException("An unexpected error occurred while running the external process.", result, null, ex);
}
```

Once the process completes, an output file is collected and returned to the user. The problem I'm running into is that after some time running like this, IIS starts dying with some relatively bizarre errors. In one test environment, we get an OutOfMemory exception during worker initialization. In another, the CLR starts failing to load .DLLs, giving a "filename or extension is too long" error. In yet another, we get a FatalExecutionEngineError. If I replace the call to actually Start() the external exe with some kind of dummy process, everything runs great.

All this suggests to me there is some kind of heap corruption bug in that .exe, but here's the kicker: If I run the exe directly against the exact same data, everything is fine.

So, two questions: is it actually possible for an .exe called via Process.Start() to corrupt the memory of the calling application without causing a protection fault itself, or am I misreading the whole situation? And how could I try to narrow this down further, given that the .exe doesn't seem to misbehave in isolation?

**Update 2/11:**

After a LOT of back and forth and running in circles and taking potshots at the code, it appears this has something to do with file IO happening in the child process. The developer of that piece has gotten involved, and if they strip out all their IO (logging, output file, etc) things begin to work properly. We're still trying to narrow down the why, but at least we have a few breadcrumbs to follow.

**Update 2/14**

It appears this was a compound issue in the child process. First, something mysterious is going bad during initialization of log4net. If we give log4net a bad configuration, or remove it entirely, we can proceed. Otherwise, we see these failures after repeated executions. Second, we have an #ifdebug section in the child process that writes a local execution statistics file. When the child executable is built for debug and that code is present, we eventually get OutOfMemory exceptions. When built for release, along with the disabling of log4net, we're able to run normally.

Comment: Odd.  Out of curiosity, why not use `process.WaitForExit()`?

Comment: This was originally written quite a while ago, and I probably just didn't notice that method at the time. This issue just surfaced as QA started hammering on things a little harder recently.

Comment: If you got an answer, add it as an answer instead of editing the question

Comment: I'm not satisfied with this as an answer. We have a workaround - don't build debug, don't use log4net - but not an real answer yet.